# How to align wordpress images properly?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, vertical-alignment

I have been working on a website in wordpress that has been doing what I need so far.
Today I tried adding a row of images (with and without captions), and for some reason the top line of the images are displaying each slightly below the other one.

You can see what I mean here:
http://rhinoaustralia.com/shop/rugby-league-jerseys/rugby-league-jerseys/

These are in newly created div classes specific for these images and I can't see why they are dropping like they are. I've dried changing the display to inline, inline-block, the margins to auto and a few other things but still no luck.
I have looked around and tried several solutions:
[How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)
but no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove <br> from your code..it is happening due to <br> code.

Comment: It is because you give <br> between div.

Comment: Can you post the html code from the text editor on your wordpress page? The result sometimes differs from the html on the page editor.

Comment: yeah, it was a case of the html editor not showing the <br> but auto inserting it in the published version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `<br>` from your code to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

```
<div id="attachment_3753" style="width: 180px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><img src="http://rhinoaustralia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/straight.png" alt="Traditional Fit"><p class="wp-caption-text">Traditional Fit</p></div>
<div id="attachment_3752" style="width: 180px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><img src="http://rhinoaustralia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/semi.png" alt="Slim Fit"><p class="wp-caption-text">Slim Fit</p></div>
<div id="attachment_3751" style="width: 180px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><img src="http://rhinoaustralia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pro.png" alt="Elite Fit"><p class="wp-caption-text">Elite Fit</p></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason in the wordpress backend in HTML mode it didn't have the <br/> showing. But it did seem to auto insert it when it it was published.

Comment: To resolve this, you can check the below link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content Hope this helps.